# InvalidCastException when casting a Collection<T> into an ObservableCollection<T> via reflection

Tags: c#, reflection, windows-phone-8.1

I can cast a `Collection<T>` to an `ObservableCollection<T>` like this:

```
ObservableCollection<MyObject> col1;
col1 = (ObservableCollection<MyObject>)new Collection<MyObject>();
```

But when I try to do it via reflection I get the following error:

```
myProperty.SetValue(
    element, 
    Convert.ChangeType(values, myProperty.PropertyType, null)
    , null);
```

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'
>   occurred in mscorlib.ni.dll Additional information: Object must
>   implement IConvertible.

Why does the conversion work in normal runtime, but not when I use reflection?

**Edit**
I ended up 'solving' my issue by not using a `Collection<T>` as a type but directly using my `myProperty.PropertyType` as type.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I can cast a `Collection<T>` to an `ObservableCollection<T>` like
>   this:
>
> ```
> ObservableCollection<MyObject> col1;
> col1 = (ObservableCollection<MyObject>)new Collection<MyObject>();
> ```

No you can't... this code also throws an `InvalidCastException`. An instance of `Collection<T>` is not an instance of an `ObservableCollection<T>`, and there is no conversion from `Collection<T>` to `ObservableCollection<T>`. It works the other way: an `ObservableCollection<T>` is a `Collection<T>`, since `ObservableCollection<T>` inherits from `Collection<T>`.

So it fails with reflection for the same reason it fails in code...

Comment: Damn it this is embarrassing. I had a compiler error without the cast, and assumed wrongly it would cast just nice.